# Can't run KDE on Arch, $DISPLAY not set

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, kde5, plasma5

I just installed Arch Linux. I have set up xorg and can start the xserver with xclock and xterm.

I have also installed plasma-desktop.

As per the [KDE - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/KDE#Installation) I only need to append `exec startkde` to the `.xinitrc` file. I did that, but upon `startx` the plasma desktop doesn't run and X server terminates.

When trying to run `startkde` on the tty I get `$DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to X server.`

*Note:* This is kde-plasma without a display manager. I want to run it from the console manually.

It will be difficult to add log files since they are on the other machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `xorg-xinit` package. The [`xinit`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit) program allows a user to manually start an Xorg display server.

```
sudo pacman -S xorg-xinit
```

In ArchWiki there's a [tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit) to use Windows Managers such as KDE without any Display Manager. To do this, add the following comands to the bottom of `~/.bash_profile` file. If the file does not exist, copy a skeleton version from `/etc/skel/.bash_profile`. For Zsh, add it to `~/.zprofile`.

```
if [[ ! $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]]; then
  exec startx
fi
```

Now you have just to create your `~/.xinitrc`

```
exec startkde
```

By doing this, X will start before you login executing the `~/.xinitrc` file, starting the KDE session.

Best regards.